# Escaping delimiter in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, delimiter

I have a ton of files which are delimited by |, however, they have | as values in the fields as well.  the | in the data has been escaped with \ but I don't think BQ is picking it up, is this something I can fix without having to open every single file, and updating?  there are 2-3000 files and are all zipped, so doing it one by one is not at all practical.

Comment: Can you specify a delimiter that doesn't appear in the data instead? Then run a query over the table to split the fields using a query.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing that, usually that's what I would do, but I have over 1000 zipped files, I'd have to unzip each one, do the edit, and then load, I dont have space for that, nor time.

Comment: No, you would load all of the files without modifying them, just specify a different delimiter so BigQuery loads them into a table with a single STRING column.

Comment: I'm being dumb here, but then what?

Comment: Then run a query that splits the STRING into separate columns, writing the result to a table. If you provide an example of the format of the data, we can help develop the query.

Comment: ahh I got you now, let me try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Read each row as a whole line (CSV, with a weird character delimiter).
2. Parse in BigQuery - either via REGEX or JavaScript UDF.

I describe a similar approach here:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6