# Get a massive csv file from GCS to BQ

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a very large CSV file (let's say 1TB) that I need to get from GCS onto BQ. While BQ does have a CSV-loader, the CSV files that I have are pretty non-standard and don't end up loading properly to BQ without formatting it.

Normally I would download the csv file onto a server to 'process it' and save it either directly to BQ or to an avro file that can be ingested easily by BQ. However, the file(s) are quite large and it's quite possible (and probably) that I wouldn't have the storage/memory to do the batch processing without writing a lot of code to optimize/stream it.

Is this a good use case for using Cloud Dataflow? Are there any tutorials are ways to go about getting a file of format "X" from GCS into BQ? Any tutorial pointers or example scripts to do so would be great.

Comment: Dataflow can do this with Python or Java, and also Dataprep can do it for you.

Comment: @Pablo are there any example links that would show how something like this could be done using Dataflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally use Dataflow (not Dataprep) and write a simple pipeline to read the file in parallel, clean/transform it, and finally write it to BigQuery. It's pretty straightforward. [Here's](https://github.com/polleyg/gcp-batch-ingestion-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/java/org/polleyg/TemplatePipeline.java) an example of one in my GitHub repo. Although it's in Java, you could easily port it to Python. Note: it uses the "templates" feature in Dataflow, but this can be changed with one line of code.

If Dataflow is off the table, another option could be to use a weird/unused delimiter and read the entire row into BigQuery. Then use SQL/Regex/UDFs to clean/transform/parse it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429988/escaping-delimiter-in-bq) (suggestion from Felipe). We've done this lots of times in the past, and because you're in BigQuery it scales really well.

Comment: very interesting approach on the above using a weird delimiter. I've used this sometimes in pandas to get all the data into one column. However, one thing we do run into in using that approach, is lines sometimes don't have a `\n` delimiter. I've seen field terminators such as `\x02`, and so a single record would span across two (or more) rows. Is there a possible way to fix that with the BQ approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/).

Dataprep can import data from GCS, clean / modify the data and export to BigQuery. One of the features that I like is that everything can be done visually / interactively so that I can see how the data transforms.

Start with a subset of your data to see what transformations are required and to give yourself some practice before loading and processing a TB of data.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. What would be the difference between using Dataflow vs Dataprep? Would either work for the job, or would Cloud Dataflow not be an option for the above?

Comment: Dataflow uses software (typically Python) and Dataprep uses a visual dashboard. Both will do what you want, just different techniques.

Comment: I tried using Dataprep's interface a few times, and each time I ran into limitations with importing files. For example, json files had to be json-newline, etc. Each time I used it I was actually unable to accomplish what I needed, so I think perhaps Dataflow would be better for this task.

Comment: A curious fact is that Dataprep generates Dataflow pipelines and runs them. Dataprep being a visual tool is more limited than writing a Dataflow pipeline with the SDK itself.

Comment: @Pablo - Agreed. Not everyone can write (or even wants to write) a Python or Java program. Some analysts want tools that are visual or drag-and-drop and don't require developers to write programs for them. I am a developer and I try to use the correct tools for the job. Sometimes this is Dataprep, sometimes Dataflow, sometimes Dataproc and sometimes a simple Python script running on GCE reading from and writing back to GCS before importing directly into BQ.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although Dataprep simply generates and runs Dataflow jobs under the hood (Apache Beam pipelines), it's actually a 3rd party tool by Trifacta re-skinned in the GCP console, so you must agree to share your account information with them before using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can always transfer from a storage bucket directly into a BQ table:

```
bq --location=US load --[no]replace --source_format=CSV dataset.table gs://bucket/file.csv [schema]
```

Here, `[schema]` can be an inline schema of your csv file (like `id:int,name:string,..`) or a path to a JSON schema file (available locally).

As per BQ documentation, they try to parallelize large CSV loads into tables. Of course, there is an upper-bound involved: maximum size of an uncompressed (csv) file to be loaded from GCS to BQ should be <= 5TB, which is way above your requirements. I think you should be good with this.

Comment: in theory this works well. However, in practice, the files are generally not "BQ-ready". For example, the (field) separator in a file might be a non-standard delimiter such as `\x01`, may not start on the first line, may have comment characters, etc. Given this requirement, how would you suggest doing it then?

Comment: from this link right here -- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv -- we would run into four of their four limitations, and our csv encoding (delimiters section) would also not work for BQ. In other words, we need to 'preprocess' the file.